# How To Go About HelloWorld,py syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

I need some help. I'm new to Python and so I've recently been following a Python tutorial online just to get myself accustomed to the language. I started off by entering the following code (and saving the file as hello.py) into Sublime:

print `("Hello, world!")`

Unfortunately, I'm now stuck. After I saved it as hello.py, I ran it into terminal from my windows desktop, this is the outcome I received:

```
python helloworld.py File "stdin", line 1 python helloworld.py SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone please explain how I can go about rectifying this please?

I've tried looking at old posts from other members to see if I could rectify this, but I have yet to find a solution. I would really appreciate it if someone could please help.

Comment: You need to post the code that gives you that error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the full contents of the file you're trying to run, the exact command your typed on the command line, and the full output of that command, all as *formatted text* (using the `{}` button in the editor). Make sure it's clear what is what. It's unclear right now what you typed in and what the output was.